# morphing a cube into sphere

Tags: ios, scenekit, morphing

This is an image from apple's documentation. They show a transform from a cube to sphere and also to some random geometry.
[image]

Only a few lines lower they state:

> A morpher and its target geometries may be loaded from a scene file or
>   created programmatically. The base geometry and all target geometries
>   must be topologically identical—that is, they must contain the same
>   number and structural arrangement of vertices.

Could someone explain this paragraph because apparently I don't understand it. 
Since a sphere will never have the same structural arrangement of vertices as cube(at least I think so), it is impossible to make transformation. But hey, we all see it in the picture. I also tried do to the transformation and I don't get the expected results. So how do you go from sphere to cube or vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Topologically identical" means that the relationships between vertices in a mesh must be preserved, but their locations in space can change. Here's an example of that in 2D:

[image: rect mesh]
[image]

These two meshes have the same eight vertices, connected to each other in the same ways, but their positions (and thus the shape they form) differ.

To do the same in 3D with SceneKit, you need custom vertex data — the primitive shapes that SceneKit can generate for you (like `SCNSphere`, `SCNBox`, and whatnot) all have different topologies, so they can't be used as morpher targets.

If you want to morph a box into a sphere, you'll need to generate your own box and sphere with identical topology. The "some random shape" in Apple's illustration is a hint at how you might do that — it appears to be one of the variants of a [superellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipsoid). If you use the equations in that Wikipedia page you can generate a set of points that can be either on a sphere or on a cube depending on other parameters. Vary those parameters to generate a couple of meshes, create `SCNGeometry` from those meshes, and you've got valid `SCNMorpher` targets.

You can see a simpler example of morphing in Apple's [SceneKit WWDC 2014 Slides](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitWWDC2014/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014551) sample app.

Comment: Wow, I did not picture structural arrangement of vertices in this way. Great explanation! I do not get a lot of replies on SceneKit questions so that makes me even more thankful. I downloaded the slides, went to AAPlSlideMorphing.m but didn't really catch where they set the morph targets:( I'm guessing I would need to use calculationMode and SCNMorpgerCalculationMode constants with superllipsoid formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can't presume the locations of each vertex in the given images; the cube doesn't neccesarily have eight and the left-most doesn't guaruntee to have 6.

Admittedly, I've not played with `SCNMorpher` but from that description I imagine it will interpolate on a per-vertex basis (so they will have to match up).

If it helps, picture the sphere as having a lot of 'dots' spread equally along its surface and those are pushed or squeezed to make the other surfaces